# What is the difference between CSS width and screen width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to determine the smallest width that media queries can expect to see on phone devices.  I googled it and came up with two interesting sites.

Ones site lists the "screen width" - [screensiz](https://screensiz.es/)

And the other lists "CSS width" - [mydevice](https://www.mydevice.io/)

The CSS width is noticeably smaller, but how are they determining this, how can I accurately set to my `max-width:` for media queries for phones.

Anything less than the smaller width would be useless as is is never triggered.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .medd_article {
     width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that a user on some devices like Windows machines can set the viewport to be as small as they like - probably best not to assume there is a minimum width.

Comment: I guess what is the smallest width that is readable?  I would assume that phone device widths are supposed to be readable?

Comment: The widths just came out as commonly used widths for phones. This wasn't planned (as there would have been an `:is-mobile` pseudo-selector or something). The CSS standard need not be concerned which device classes exist. "Just design it so every width looks good" is the easiest approach for now.